# FSL installation in Ubuntu FAILED message

Tags: software-installation

I am a traditional Windows user and therefore you have to excuse me for my lack of experience with other OS. I installed Ubuntu in order to install FSL in my computer (seems the Windows installation failed so I tried this). However, the download goes right, but at the end it says "[FAILED] Unable to unpack FSL". How can I solve it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: fsl itself suggests not to run the script as root. It makes me suspicious that this is necessary instead of asking for admin password at necessary step(s). If I did this I would be closely monitoring computer and network activity afterward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FSL requires *python2.7* which can be installed in Ubuntu with `sudo apt update && sudo apt install python2.7`

FSL is installed to the `/usr/local/` directory by default, so instead of starting the FSL install script with `python fslinstaller.py` start the install script with `sudo python fslinstaller.py`, otherwise you will get an error message because you haven't given the FSL install script permission to unpack FSL to the `/usr/local/` directory.

When the FSL installation is finished, bring up a simple GUI which is just a menu of the main individual FSL GUI tools by opening the terminal and  running `fsl`.